# What is the correct way of reshaping a Data Frame in order to use it with .fit() function in ScikitLearn?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

The `coef_` & `intercept_` function outputs arrays with unexpected values.

My question is:

Is there anything wrong with my Jupyter Notebook or I am coding things wrong?
It will be a great help if someone please explain me the concept of reshaping because how hard I try I am not getting it right.

Code files can be found at: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TgSgcWaWPmqRldt0MPeoYUbSq_dsv9aa

I tried reshaping as `X.reshape(-1, 1)` and it throws error for reshaping. Then I tried making some changes to `X` and `Y` by making them data frames as:

```
X = DataFrame(df, columns='production_budget_usd')
y = DataFrame(df, columns='worldwide_gross_usd')
```

But when make data frames like this the plots behave abnormally.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('cost_revenue_clean.csv')
X = df['production_budget_usd']
y = df['worldwide_gross_usd']

X = X.reshape(1,- 1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X,y)

print(linreg.coef_)
print(linreg.intercept_)
```

Expected output:

```
array([[3.11150918]])
array([-7236192.72913963])
```

output got:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])

       array([2.60000000e+01, 4.01000000e+02, 4.23000000e+02, ...,
              2.05866222e+09, 2.20761567e+09, 2.78391898e+09])
```

Comment: You could try using `df[['production_budget_usd']].values` - Essentially giving a matrix and then do `df['worldwide_gross_usd'].values` to obtain the data you want. The `.values` creates the matrix of the dataset, the double square brackets creates the matrix whilst a single bracket with the values call creates a series.

Comment: thanks trying it now. Can you recommend an article or video that explains the concept of fit and matrices together.

Comment: Thanks it did the magic.

Comment: Awesome. In terms of the concept of fit - you typically for most single output models will provide a 1-D array but for the features it is a matrix which can be 1 dimensional as above. If you ask another question with some context of what you want to know about fit etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not recommended using `from pandas import DataFrame`
You can try those two solutions:

First Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("cost_revenue_clean.csv")
X = df['production_budget_usd']
y = df['worldwide_gross_usd']

linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X.values.reshape(-1,1),y)

print(linreg.coef_)
print(linreg.intercept_)

[3.11150918]
-7236192.729139581
```

Second Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("cost_revenue_clean.csv")
X = df[['production_budget_usd']]
y = df['worldwide_gross_usd']

#X = X.reshape(1,- 1) # no need for it since X is pandas DataFrame now.

linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X,y)

print(linreg.coef_)
print(linreg.intercept_)

[3.11150918]
-7236192.729139581
```